# Child Divs Inaccessible when Parent Div Rotated Perpendicular to Screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with CSS3 Javascript to generate a 3D cube which will be animated to transition between sides. Each side of the cube is a div, inside which I can put content. Currently, I control the transforms using input keys in order to test various scenarios.

The overall setup is thus: a parent div is placed at a given (X, Y) coordinate with no Z component. The six divs which create the cube are all placed in the center of the parent div and transformed to the correct 3-dimensional locations. The parent div is then transformed to rotate/translate/scale the cube in 3D.

The problem I am having is this: Anytime the plane of the parent div is parallel to the z-axis, the child divs are no longer interactable.

When the parent div is rotated by +-90 degrees about the X or Y axis (essentially turning the parent div sideways) the content on the cube is no longer accessible - you cannot interact with the cube. For the sake of my application, one side of the cube has a Google map on it. The parent div can be rotated to any other position and the map is interactable. See code sample:

```js
var adc = adc || {};
adc.body = null;
adc.keyState = {};
adc.obj = null;
adc.divs = [];
adc.box = [2,7];
adc.init = { 
 containers: function() {
  adc.divs[0] = adc.div.extend({dx: 0.0000, dy: 0.0000, dz: 0.0000, ax: -22.00, ay: -22.00, az: 0.0000, sx: 1.0000, sy: 1.0000, sz: 1.0000, p: 000, tStyle: "preserve-3d", tOrigin: "50% 50%", pOrigin: "50% 50%"});  
  adc.divs[1] = adc.div.extend({dx: 0.0000, dy: 0.0000, dz: 0.0000, ax: 0.0000, ay: 0.0000, az: 0.0000, sx: 1.0000, sy: 1.0000, sz: 1.0000, p: 000, tStyle: "none", tOrigin: "50% 50%", pOrigin: "50% 50%"});
  adc.divs[2] = adc.div.extend({dx: 0.0000, dy: 0.0000, dz: 251.00, ax: 0.0000, ay: 0.0000, az: 0.0000, sx: 1.0000, sy: 1.0000, sz: 1.0000, p: 000, tStyle: "preserve-3d", tOrigin: "50% 50%", pOrigin: "50% 50%"});
  adc.divs[3] = adc.div.extend({dx: 103.00, dy: 0.0000, dz: 153.00, ax: 0.0000, ay: 90.000, az: 0.0000, sx: 1.0000, sy: 1.0000, sz: 1.0000, p: 000, tStyle: "preserve-3d", tOrigin: "50% 50%", pOrigin: "50% 50%"});
  adc.divs[4] = adc.div.extend({dx: -101.0, dy: 0.0000, dz: 150.00, ax: 0.0000, ay: 90.000, az: 0.0000, sx: 1.0000, sy: 1.0000, sz: 1.0000, p: 000, tStyle: "preserve-3d", tOrigin: "50% 50%", pOrigin: "50% 50%"});
  adc.divs[5] = adc.div.extend({dx: 0.0000, dy: -101.0, dz: 150.00, ax: 90.000, ay: 0.0000, az: 0.0000, sx: 1.0000, sy: 1.0000, sz: 1.0000, p: 000, tStyle: "preserve-3d", tOrigin: "50% 50%", pOrigin: "50% 50%"});
  adc.divs[6] = adc.div.extend({dx: 0.0000, dy: 101.00, dz: 150.00, ax: 90.000, ay: 0.0000, az: 0.0000, sx: 1.0000, sy: 1.0000, sz: 1.0000, p: 000, tStyle: "preserve-3d", tOrigin: "50% 50%", pOrigin: "50% 50%"});
  adc.divs[7] = adc.div.extend({dx: 0.0000, dy: 0.0000, dz: 49.000, ax: 0.0000, ay: 0.0000, az: 0.0000, sx: 1.0000, sy: 1.0000, sz: 1.0000, p: 000, tStyle: "preserve-3d", tOrigin: "50% 50%", pOrigin: "50% 50%"});
  adc.divs[8] = adc.div.extend({dx: 0.0000, dy: 0.0000, dz: 0.0000, ax: 0.0000, ay: 0.0000, az: 0.0000, sx: 1.0000, sy: 1.0000, sz: 1.0000, p: 000, tStyle: "none", tOrigin: "50% 50%", pOrigin: "50% 50%"});

  adc.divs[0].init(['div viewport', 'absolute', 150, 150, 300, 300, 1, 'solid', '', '', '5px 5px 5px 5px', '', '', '0px', '', 'none']);  
  adc.divs[1].init(['div keyMap',   'absolute', 0,     0, 200, 400, 2,  'none', '', '', '0px 0px 0px 0px', '', '', '0px', '', 'none']);
  adc.divs[2].init(['div front',   'absolute', 50,   50, 200, 200, 4, 'solid', '', '', '5px 5px 5px 5px', '', '', '0px', '', 'yellow']);
  adc.divs[3].init(['div right',   'absolute', 50,   50, 200, 200, 3,  'none', '', '', '0px 0px 0px 0px', '', '', '0px', '', 'none']);
  adc.divs[4].init(['div left',   'absolute', 50,   50, 200, 200, 4, 'solid', '', '', '5px 5px 5px 5px', '', '', '0px', '', 'red']);
  adc.divs[5].init(['div top',   'absolute', 50,   50, 200, 200, 4, 'solid', '', '', '5px 5px 5px 5px', '', '', '0px', '', 'green']);
  adc.divs[6].init(['div bottom',   'absolute', 50,   50, 200, 200, 4, 'solid', '', '', '5px 5px 5px 5px', '', '', '0px', '', 'purple']);
  adc.divs[7].init(['div back',   'absolute', 50,   50, 200, 200, 4, 'solid', '', '', '5px 5px 5px 5px', '', '', '0px', '', 'blue']);
  adc.divs[8].init(['div gmap',   'absolute', 0,     0, 200, 200, 5, 'solid', '', '', '5px 5px 5px 5px', '', '', '0px', '', 'blue']);
  
  adc.body = document.getElementById('body');
  for(i=0; i<=adc.box[1]; i++) {
   if(i < adc.box[0]) {adc.body.appendChild(adc.divs[i].div);} 
   else {adc.divs[0].div.appendChild(adc.divs[i].div);}
  }
  
  this.getMap(adc.divs[8].div, adc.divs[3].div);
  adc.specOps.txt(adc.divs[1].div, ["Translate: Arrow Keys", "Rotate:    W - up about x-axis       S - down about x-axis", "           A - left about y-axis     D - right about y-axis", "           Q - stnd left rotate      E - stnd right rotate", "Scale:     R - scale down x-axis     T - scale up x-axis", "           F - scale down y-axis     G - scale up y-axis", "           C - scale down z-axis     V - scale up z-axis", "SPACEBAR: Console Output Transform Matrix & Perspective"]);
  
  adc.obj = adc.divs[0];
 },
 getMap: function(obj, wrap) {
  var map_options = {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
   zoom: 8,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(obj, map_options);
  wrap.appendChild(obj);
 }
}

adc.transform = {
 new: function() {
  this.getDelt();
  this.applyT();
 },
 getDelt: function() {
  if(adc.keyState[39]) {adc.obj.dx++;}
  if(adc.keyState[37]) {adc.obj.dx--;}
  if(adc.keyState[40]) {adc.obj.dy++;}
  if(adc.keyState[38]) {adc.obj.dy--;}
  if(adc.keyState[88]) {adc.obj.dz++;}
  if(adc.keyState[90]) {adc.obj.dz--;}
  if(adc.keyState[87]) {adc.obj.ax++;}
  if(adc.keyState[83]) {adc.obj.ax--;}
  if(adc.keyState[68]) {adc.obj.ay++;}
  if(adc.keyState[65]) {adc.obj.ay--;}
  if(adc.keyState[69]) {adc.obj.az++;}
  if(adc.keyState[81]) {adc.obj.az--;}
  if(adc.keyState[84]) {adc.obj.sx+=0.01;}
  if(adc.keyState[82]) {adc.obj.sx-=0.01;}
  if(adc.keyState[71]) {adc.obj.sy+=0.01;}
  if(adc.keyState[70]) {adc.obj.sy-=0.01;}
  if(adc.keyState[86]) {adc.obj.sz+=0.01;}
  if(adc.keyState[67]) {adc.obj.sz-=0.01;}
  if(adc.keyState[89]) {adc.obj.p++;}
  if(adc.keyState[72]) {adc.obj.p--;}
 },
 applyT: function() {  
  adc.obj.setTransform();
  if(adc.keyState[32]) {console.log(adc.obj.div.style.transform, adc.obj.div.style.perspective);}
 }
}

window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
  adc.keyState[e.keyCode || e.which] = true;
 adc.transform.new();
},true);

window.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
 adc.keyState[e.keyCode || e.which] = false;
},true);

adc.div = {
 div: null,
 init: function (a) {
  this.div = document.createElement('div');
  this.div.id =     a[0];
  this.div.style.position =   a[1];
  this.div.style.top =    a[2] + 'px';
  this.div.style.left =    a[3] + 'px';
  this.div.style.height =   a[4] + 'px';
  this.div.style.width =    a[5] + 'px';
  this.div.style.zIndex =   a[6];
  this.div.style.borderStyle =   a[7];
  this.div.style.borderWidth =   a[8];
  this.div.style.borderColor =   a[9];
  this.div.style.borderRadius =   a[10];
  this.div.style.textAlign =   a[11];
  this.div.style.verticalAlign =   a[12];
  this.div.style.padding =   a[13];
  this.div.style.whiteSpace =   a[14];
  this.div.style.backgroundColor =  a[15];
  this.div.style.backgroundImage =  a[16];
  this.setTransform();
 },
 dx: 0.0,
 dy: 0.0,
 dz: 0.0,
 ax: 0.0,
 ay: 0.0,
 az: 0.0,
 sx: 1.0,
 sy: 1.0,
 sz: 1.0,
 p: 0,
 tStyle: "",
 tOrigin: "",
 pOrigin: "",
 setTransform: function() {
  this.div.style.transformStyle = this.tStyle;
  this.div.style.perspectiveOrigin = this.pOrigin;
  this.div.style.perspective = this.p + "px";
  this.div.style.transformOrigin = this.tOrigin;
  this.div.style.transform = adc.specOps.mtx([this.dx, this.dy, this.dz, this.ax, this.ay, this.az, this.sx, this.sy, this.sz]);
 },
 extend: function(props) {
  var prop, obj;
  obj = Object.create(this);
  for(prop in props) {
   if(props.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    obj[prop] = props[prop];
   }
  }
  return obj;
 }
}

adc.specOps = {
 mtx: function(a) {
  return "translateX(" + a[0] + "px) translateY(" + a[1] + "px) translateZ(" + a[2] + "px) rotateX(" + a[3] + "deg) rotateY(" + a[4] + "deg) rotateZ(" + a[5] + "deg) scaleX(" + a[6] + ") scaleY(" + a[7] + ") scaleZ(" + a[8] + ")";
 },
 txt: function(a, b) {
  var pr = document.createElement("pre")
  for(i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
   pr.innerHTML += b[i];
   pr.innerHTML += "<br>";
  }
  a.appendChild(pr);
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body id="body">
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
  </script>
  <script src="main.js">
  </script>
  <script>
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    adc.init.containers();
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I checked the visibility component of the parent div and it remains "visible" at all times. I know I can jerry-rig the system to do what I want -- imperceptibly change the orientation of the parent div and swap the cube faces around at the completion of the animation. But, I'd like to know if there is a way to use the concept as-is.

Or, is there a better way to animate 3D shapes composed of divs?

Thank you in advance for any time and consideration.

Comment: What browser are you running?  Your map on you cube in your code snippet above IS interactable.

Comment: The map is only not interactable when the parent div is parallel to the z-axis. I did test the snippet, the issue detailed above should occur. It is best viewed in Full Page.

Comment: Try using "a" until the parent div (solid border behind the cube) disappears. Use "d" to correct over-rotation.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, I see your problem now.  Hmmmmmm.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue once for a 3d terrain map. For any rotation by 90 degrees, when the parent div (`viewport` in your case) is perpendicular to the screen, the width (or height) of this element becomes zero and thus (for whatever reason) is "hidden" from interactions.

My solution (even though it is not really addressing the cause) was to add a wrapper div (`<div id="viewport-wrapper"><div id="viewport">...</div></div>`) and the following CSS:

```
#viewport-wrapper {
  transform: rotateY(0.01deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

This minimal rotation (not even visible on most screens or if only barely) ensures that the actual `#viewport` is never truly perpendicular and thus stays interactive.

Comment: Regarding the deleted comment: Well, I don't know for _any_ number, but I tried with one, two and three wrappers and always had some issues. At some point I even had a javascript function which would rotate two wrappers at once to avoid 90 degree angles, but would rotate both 45 degrees.

Comment: I realized I commented without exploring on my own, hence the deletion. It seems though that yes, it doesn't matter what the setup is - if any div becomes exactly perpendicular to the screen it's children are inaccessible.

Comment: I had thought about using multiple wrappers like you said, moving each 45 degrees on their own. Did that get complicated for multi-directional movements? I agree with you that the small offset angle of a single wrapper is imperceptible, it may work for my application.

Comment: Getting complicated? You bet. It's working alright if you allow rotation for one axis, only. I finally dropped that, also because I didn't only allow increments of whole degrees (like in your app) but free movement (drag&drop).